# Create thumbnail from wowza stream

Tags: stream, thumbnails, wowza

I try to get thumbnail like http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?229-How-to-take-a-single-frame-snapshot-of-a-live-stream-for-thumbnail-creation-(ModuleCreateSnapshot)
But I get error like in last post of this forum.

```
[flv @ 0x7ff42380e600] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
[flv @ 0x7ff42380e600] Could not find codec parameters for stream 1 (Audio: none, 0 channels): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
dLR.flv.flv: could not find codec parameters
Input #0, flv, from 'dLR.flv.flv':
  Metadata:
    creationdate    : Fri Jul 17 17:03:12
  Duration: 00:00:00.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264, 1k tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: none, 0 channels
Output #0, image2, to 'q.flv.png':
  Metadata:
    creationdate    : Fri Jul 17 17:03:12
Output file #0 does not contain any stream
```

Comment: Your `flv` doesn't seem valid. Are you able to play it back?

Comment: With vlc player - no. Actually, this flv file is information of headers and 1 chunk of media stream. But it is much enough to create picture file.

Comment: The file seems empty (no stream).